# converting tuple to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to convert a line of string to dictionary where i am facing an error.
here is what i have and what i did:

```
line="nsd-1:quorum"
t=tuple(line.split(":"))
d=dict(t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    d=dict(t)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required
```

Basically, what i want to achieve is to have a key value pair.
So if i have set of values separated by a ":", i want to have it as a key whatever is before the colon and after the colon needs to be the value for the key.
example: if i take the above string, i want "nsd-1" as my key and "quorum" as value.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap it in a list:

```
>>> dict([t])
{'nsd-1': 'quorum'}
```

There's also no need to convert the return value of `split` to a tuple:

```
>>> dict([line.split(':')])
{'nsd-1': 'quorum'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put `t` inside an empty list, like this:

```
d=dict([t])
```